# AndEngine Wallpaper rotate screen error

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I'm developing Android live wallpaper on AndEngine framework. In moment when i change screen orientation in emulator wallpaper crashed with error:

```
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 154
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at org.andengine.opengl.util.GLHelper.getPixelsARGB_8888(GLHelper.java:165)
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at org.andengine.opengl.util.GLHelper.getPixels(GLHelper.java:41)
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at org.andengine.opengl.util.GLState.glTexImage2D(GLState.java:637)
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTexture.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTexture.java:120)
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at org.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:137)
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:254)
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:613)
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at org.andengine.extension.opengl.GLThread.guardedRun(GLThread.java:219)
09-05 14:25:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1310):     at org.andengine.extension.opengl.GLThread.run(GLThread.java:95)
```

Error appear only when in wallpaper many animated sprites. Anybody can help me?
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the error means you don't have enough memory. Apparently when the orientation changes, the application reloads the sprites to memory without having unloaded the old ones first. You can try calling `System.gc()` when the orientation changes to free the memory occupied by the now useless sprites. You can also attempt to unload them manually, because you may have a memory leak there.

See this lecture, it could help you:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk